# JUnit execute program @before

Tags: java, junit4

I'm using JUnit and now I want to execute a Java program (main method) before running the tests.

I.e. in my project I have a package with a class which has a main method. This I want to run (perhaps in a separate process) before I run my tests because the classes under test will connect to his process via sockets.

How can I do that?

And at the end I want to kill this process of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost answered yourself. You need to launch this process in separate thread using either Runtime.exec() (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) or some more sophisticated tool like so Apache Commons Exec http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/index.html

Method annotated with '@Before' or '@BeforeClass' annotation can be good place to do this. The best way would be to program extra helper class as singleton. This class will be responsible for launching the thread only in case it was not launched before, so you will have only one process for all the tests.

---

Edit: It should be something like:

```
 @BeforeClass
  public static void startProess() throws Exception {
    SomeProcess .getInstance().startIfNotRunning();
  }

public class SomeProcess {
  private Thread thread;
  private Process process;


  private static SomeProcess instance = new SomeProcess ();
  public static SomeProcess getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }

  public synchronized void startIfNotRunning() throws Exception {
      (...) 
      // check if it's not running and if not start
      (...)
      instance.start();
      (...)
  }

  public synchronized void stop() throws Exception {
      process.destroy()
  }

 private synchronized void start() throws Exception {
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           process = Runtime.exec("/path/yo/your/app");
        }

      });


    thread.start();

    // put some code to wait until the process has initialized (if it requires some time for initialization.

  }

}
```

Comment: But in this way the program is executed as a thread and not as a process?

Comment: You will have a thread which will run separate process. By this I mean it creates new process in operating system. See java docs of   [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) . Runtime.exec() returns an instance of Process class which is connected to native process which is launched in operating system. You can use this returned instance of Process to communicated with it- you can read console output of this process for example.

Comment: How can I kill the process in the after clause in JUnit?

Comment: Store the instance of Process returned by Runtime.exe() (I edited the example according this). And later just call process.destroy(). I edited again to create stop() method. So on @AfterClass you call SomeProcess.getInstance().stop()

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this new process create a new JVM instance? Like launching the program from command line.

Comment: No.. consider that what you launch does not need to be a java application. If you launch java app by running something like Runtime.exe("java -jar myapp.jar") than of course new jvm will be created, but if you launch Runtime.exe("/bin/bash") than it will be "normal" process in operating system having nothing to do with java. PS. if I answered your problem please "Accept" it as a solution :)

Comment: Now I understand. ;) But I have a small last question. If I have two java programs running in separate processes (e.g. by calling Runtime.exe("java -jar myapp.jar")), can then a programm access methods of another program in another process?

Comment: You should really ask separate question about this but... generally no because these are separate jvms. There are however many ways to achieve such integration. See my answer in this post for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065917/cross-context-communication-between-two-web-application-deployed-on-same-tomcat/26066523#26066523. Cheers:)

Comment: Sorry for again asking here. What is the difference between creating a new JVM with e.g. Runtime.exe("java -jar myapp.jar") and executing the java programm just as a new process within the existing JVM?

Comment: What do you mean by "executing the java programm just as a new process within the existing JVM"?

Comment: I mean that the program is executed as a new process (operating system process) but within the same JVM. Is this not possible?

Comment: This is exactly what you achieve by calling  Runtime.exe("java -jar myapp.jar"). You create new operation system process, which happens to be another instance of java application. Both options, you asked about are the same thing.